# How to get data from UITableView cell to a global variable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to save the text of a cell within my `UITableView` for later usage. I saw on a different Stack Overflow posts it was recommended to use

```
sender.view
```

when I print it out to the console, the respose is:

```
Optional(<UITableViewCell: 0x7f8e0a803400; frame = (0 0; 375 50); text = 'Event 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60400024f150>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400002b940>>)
```

However when I try to access

```
sender.view?.text
```

XCode shows an error saying

```
Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'text'
```

I have not found any ways to get the text from a UIView, is it even possible, if so how?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:

sender is a `UITapGestureRecognizer` I am passing into the method from the button press

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    cell.textLabel?.text = mydata[indexPath.item]
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return cell
}


@objc func handleTapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToScanner", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: text from the view will be in a label. So you have to get the value from the label. Assuming your sender is of the type your custom cell, you should call `sender.label.text` to get the text from the cell.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri but then I get: Value of type 'UITapGestureRecognizer' has no member 'label'

Comment: your sender is a tap gesture. You should show your code. This is totally out of context.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I edited my question to show the code

Comment: Try to cast sender.view as UITableViewCell. Then you should be able to access the textLabel.text from the cell.

    guard let cell = sender.view as? UITableViewCell else { return }
    cell.textLabel.text

Comment: @Elhoej Thanks, your suggestion solved my problem. If you want to submit that as the answer to the question I can mark it as correct so you get reputation points. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the sender.view as a UITableViewCell, then you should be able to access the cell's textLabel.

```
guard let cell = sender.view as? UITableViewCell else {
    //error handling
    return
}

let text = cell.textLabel.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why're using a tap gesture recognizer over a tableView cell. Here's another solution which might be of use to you.

You can use 
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` delegate method from `UITableViewDelegate`

In your case it should look something like this.

```
extension YourViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell {
             let text = cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

Make sure your `ViewController` conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` in `viewDidLoad`